# How to import trained tf.contrib.learn.dnnclassifier using C_API

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, c-api

How can a trained DNNClassifer be imported using C_API? I tried using TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel, but it raised the following error:

*I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:284] Loading SavedModel: fail.*

Here is the C part of code:

```
    const char* export_dir = "path_to_trained_model/folder_with_trained_model";
    const char* tags_[1] = {"import"};

    TF_Graph* graph_new = TF_NewGraph();
    TF_Buffer* meta_graph_def= TF_NewBuffer();
    TF_SessionOptions* opt = TF_NewSessionOptions();
    TF_Buffer* run_options = TF_NewBufferFromString("", 0);
    TF_Status* s = TF_NewStatus();

    TF_Session* session1= TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel(
            opt, run_options,  export_dir,
            tags_, 1,  graph_new,
            meta_graph_def, s);
```

Comment: you want to train this model with c++ ? or just load a frozen model and run inference ?

Comment: just load the trained model and run evaluation; the model is trained as tf.contrib.learn.dnnclassifier and i have the checkpoints and graph saved in defined directory

Comment: do you have the frozen model ? usually with extension .pb  ?

Comment: i could not freeze a dnnclassifier, but i have .pbtxt (which can be also translated to .pb) as well as .meta and .index files saved at checkpoints

Comment: well sorry then. i know how to load and use the .pb file. when you save it as frozen model using python.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same error. What helped me was to actually take a look at what **TF_Message(s)** (this expression should return a null-terminated c-string (i.e. char*)) points to.